# Can I make a pecan pie with corn syrup only?

Tags: baking, substitutions, sugar, pie

I want to make a fructose free one for my dad. I am not a fan of sugar substitutes, either. Karo doesn't have fructose but sugar does. If I left out the sugar could I use corn syrup only or would it not set up?

Answer (score 2):

It would seem to me that controlling the total amount of water in the recipe will be the trick, so you'll want a crystallized or powdered replacement for the table sugar rather than a syrup.

I've not tried it myself, but you might try using dextrose in place of the table sugar.  Dextrose is the commercial name for crystalline glucose, and I found it readily available on Amazon ([https://www.amazon.com/Now-Foods-Dextrose-2-Lbs/dp/B008MVJKFU/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008MVJKFU)).

Normally when substituting one kind of sugar for another, assume 7 oz (by weight) per cup of sugar specified in your recipe, then weigh out that much of your alternative.  But there are multiple sources online that state dextrose is only about 70% as sweet, meaning you'd want to divide by 0.7 to adjust the quantity from sucrose to dextrose.  Here's a typical reference, though there were many others with the same information: http://www.livestrong.com/article/534691-how-to-bake-with-dextrose/

I'd love to know whether or not it works!  If you try it, leave a comment and let us know how it goes.

Comment: Or, if like many people, you find pecan pies to be overly sweet anyway, you could leave the measurements the same.

Comment: Thanks! I was googling around and someone else suggested dextrose as a replacement for table sugar in the recipe, but I wasn't quite sure how much to use. Thanks for this answer.